# Zoomable chart with data from ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Since I'm new to web programming (not programming in general) I have a basic question:

I'm trying to build a zoomable chart with data from my ajax responsem, in APS.NET MVC:

My ajax response is a list of these objects:

```
public sealed class mVTCModel 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
        public bool Valid { get; set; }
        public double mVTC { get; set; }
    }
```

I've tried a lot of diffrent stuff. I have this code in my View:

title

```
</div>

<script type="application/javascript">

    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/api/Api',
          data: { },
          success:function(response)
          {
              console.time('line');
              Highcharts.chart('container', {

                chart: {
                  zoomType: 'x'
                },

                title: {
                  text: 'Power Query mVTC'
                },

                subtitle: {
                  text: ''
                },

                tooltip: {
                  valueDecimals: 2
                },

                xAxis: {
                  type: 'datetime'
                },

                series: [{
                  data: response,
                  lineWidth: 0.5,
                  name: 'Hourly data points'
                }]

              });
              console.timeEnd('line');


          },
          error:function(){

          }
        });


</script>
```

I **believe** my problem is here:

```
    series: [{
              data: response, <-- HERE (I suppose)
              lineWidth: 0.5,
              name: 'Hourly data points'
            }]
```

Since I do not tell the chart what is the x-axis and what is the Y-axis.

So in short how do I map the x-axis to **LogTime** and y-axis to **mVTC**

Comment: [`Data`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data) is an array where each element should look like this: `{x: mVTCModel.LogTime, y: mVTCModel.mVTC}`. If you want to display the id/Valid state you can make the element look like this: `{x: mVTCModel.LogTime, y: mVTCModel.mVTC, customId: mVTCModel.Id, customValidState: mVTCModel.Valid}`, and then reference them when needed. So you need the transform the response into an array like that.

Comment: Your data object should be appropriately composed. Here's explained how to do it: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series